# JSF client-side event framework to reduce coupling and network traffic

Tags: javascript, jsf-2.2, omnifaces

A Web Page contains both 'static' HTML elements (they will never be updated) and 'dynamic' elements, which are updated by some JavaScript code. In server-side technologies like JSF, it's quite easy and convenient to let the server regenerate entire blocks of HTML elements (on an AJAX request), and while this can be done with almost no extra work (and this is one of the reasons why I appreciate JSF so much), sometimes this technique is not efficient in terms of network traffic and server load.

Let's take an example, where we have a composite component and a using page.

The composite component is as follows:

```
<cc:implementation>
    <div id="#{cc.clientId}">       
        <div>
            <!-- block of HTML elements that don't have to be updated -->
        </div>

        <div jsf:id="some-part">
            <!-- block of HTML elements that we would like to update -->
        </div>
    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

And the using page:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Press me">
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.someListener()}" render="component"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>

<!-- somewhere else in the page -->
<my:component id="component"/>
```

When the button is pressed, a partial update will take place where the HTML code of the composite component will be re-rendered by the server. However, this is not efficient, because we actually don't need to update the whole component, but only a (possibly small) part of it.

The second problem I can see with this approach is the coupling between the button and the composite component. In this trivial example, it may not be a real problem. But in more complex Web Pages, such coupling may not be desired because it may lead to more maintenance costs.

I did not find any framework to do that. So I've implemented one. If you know such a framework, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

The composite component is changed into:

```
<cc:implementation>
    <div id="#{cc.clientId}">       
        <div>
            <!-- block of HTML elements that don't have to be updated -->
        </div>

        <div jsf:id="some-part">
            <!-- block of HTML elements that we would like to update -->
        </div>

        <!-- add an event observer that will only update the needed parts -->
        <h:form>
            <steappe:eventObserver event="some-semantic-event"
                                   listener="#{beans.someListener()}"
                                   render=":#{cc.clientId}:some-part"/>
        </h:form>
    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

And the using page is changed into:

```
<!-- add an event producer that reacts on the button click  - no form needed here -->
<h:commandButton value="Press me">
    <steappe:eventProducer on="click" event="some-semantic-event"/>
</h:commandButton>

<!-- somewhere else in the page -->
<my:component id="component"/>
```

There is no coupling between the button and the component anymore. The button just fires a semantic event, and does not care about what will happen with this event.

The composite component observes the semantic event and when such an event is fired, it updates only the parts that need to be updated.

This event framework can also be used with web sockets (I use those of Onmifaces), in order to update the Web Page automatically.

```
<o:socket channel="some-channel" onmessage="steppe.eventing.dispatchSocketMessage"/>

<!-- somewhere else in the page -->
<my:component id="component"/>
```

When a message is sent by the server to the client through the Web Socket, and if this message is a raw string, then this message is considered an event and is dispatched to all the observers.

**Implementation**

The implementation is still in BETA, and is available on github at the following address: https://github.com/steappe/jsf-eventing

I've tested this approach in a test environment based on code currently in production, and it can reduce the network traffic by up to 70% in some cases.

Of course, there could be some drawbacks to this approach that I would not have seen. In this case please feel free to respond, and give me advice. Thanks :)